# Is it a bad practice to base logic on assumption that a type is a struct?

Tags: c#, struct

In my current project, I need to throw a lot of data around with a good understanding of what is a copy and what is a reference, in particular — implement a lot of deep cloning. Thankfully, a lot of my data is contained in simple structs, so I can just assign them or pass them as parameters and be sure that they aren't referencing each other.

However, I realized that the code that is doing that is based on assumption that these types are struct, and that if anyone is going to change their type to a class some time down the road, they may not notice errors right away, and when they do, it will be a hell to debug.

In general, I consider code which correctness is based on assumption that is not explicitly stated in the same file to be a smell, and especially when this assumption can be changed without immediately breaking the build. So, this situation really gives a bad smell for me.

Is what I'm doing really a bad practice? Have you experienced any problems that I described in real codebases, or am I imagining things? And if you have, what would be a good way to make things more explicit?

---

Here's an example of what I'm talking about (this is my actual code, with all names changed and other functionality stripped):

```
public class Example
{
    public readonly DataOfType;
    public readonly DataOfOtherType;

    public Example(Type _DataOfType, OtherType _DataOfOtherType)
    {
        DataOfType = _DataOfType;
        DataOfOtherType = _DataOfOtherType;
    }

    public Example DeepClone()
    {
        return new Example(DataOfType, DataOfOtherType);
    }
}
```

The `DeepClone` method is correct because `Type` is an enum and `OtherType` is a struct, but you would never know it from this code.

Comment: Could you please post a part of your code that shows that you have described. Thanks

Comment: @Christos updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a generic constrained to only allow structs, but uncreatable, and then create variables of that type at the top of each method where the assumption is required.

E.g.:

```
public class AssumeStruct<TStruct> where TStruct : struct
{
    private AssumeStruct(){}
}
```

And then:

```
public void MethodAssumingStructSemantics(S1 arg1)
{
   AssumeStruct<S1> t = null;
   ...
}
```

This should then cause a compiler error if the nature of the `S1` type is changed later.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of thinking of data in terms of references and copies, I think that you should think about it in terms of mutability.

If you have an immutable type, then it doesn't matter if it is a struct or a class, you can treat it the same becase you know that it can't change. You can safely pass it around without caring about whether it's a reference or a copy, that becomes just an implementation detail.

Whenever you need to change a value, the immutability will force you to create a copy. That way you can never mess up a value in one place that is used in another place.

The `String` class is an example of how this is used. As strings are immutable you can pass them around as references without the risk of a string ever changing. All the methods in the `String` class that makes changes to a string will create a new string with the result.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the `struct` immutable, which it should be in my opinion, you won't have issues with references being spread once the `struct` becomes a class.

Besides that, I think you have to help the 'maintainer' and 'user' of the `struct` to understand the implications.

You can easily do that with a `remarks` section in your Visual Studio code documentation. This will pop up on every one referencing the type.

I wouldn't make too much changes to the code to show the data type is a `struct` or do some type checking. This may only lead to confusion.